# react fireabase Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to import this library to use firebase feature import firebase from 'firebase/app';
It is giving below error
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"
at line
{
function(module, exports) {

import firebase from '@firebase/app';
export { default } from '@firebase/app';

var name = "firebase";
var version = "8.8.1";
........
}